# I cant figure out how to animate particle rotation

Tags: particles

I am trying to make a background for a video, where there are glowing particles falling down while rotating. i have it so that they fall at a set rate, and the rotation is randomized, but i can't figure out how to actually animate the rotation of the particles. any help with this question is appreciated, thank you!

edit: animating the particle object DOES NOT work.

Comment: You'll need to include more details before anyone here can try to help you. For instance add images of the problem, and what settings you have.

Comment: You could animate the particle object itself?

Comment: Are the particles Spheres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "rotation" menu in the particle settings. Check "Dynamic" and, under "Angular Velocity", choose the desired axis and increase the amount from 0 to the desired rotation speed.

[image]